# Executing method of a class multiple times parallel

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an array- say wordsArray where each object of wordArray is another array- say wordList. With for loop i am picking each object (wordList) and call a method -say wordScore of another class which will return `NSDictionary` with word and the score. Instead of calling wordScore for each object one by one, Is there a way I can run them parallel? wordScore for each wordList should execute in parallel and at the end of execution all the `NSDictionaries` of each wordScore should be merged into a single `NSDictionary`.

Comment: See [Concurrency Programming Guide: Performing Loop Iterations Concurrently](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW23). Be warned that you (a) have to synchronize your updates to the final dictionary to make sure it's done in a thread-safe manner; and (b) the performance gain of concurrent calculations will by offset by overhead of coordinating the activity on multiple threads, sometimes entirely wiping out any performance gain you may have hoped for.

Comment: add your code here for better help

Comment: Bottom line, use `dispatch_apply`, but make sure you've got enough going on each thread to justify the overhead of `dispatch_apply` and the synchronization of the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say I have something silly like this class

```
@interface MyWordClass: NSObject
- (NSDictionary *)wordScore:(NSArray *)wordList;
@end

@implementation MyWordClass
- (NSDictionary *)wordScore:(NSArray *)wordList {
    NSMutableDictionary *scores = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    for (NSString *word in wordList) {
        scores[word] = @(word.hash %100);
    }
    return [scores copy];
}
@end
```

From here, I'll do a concurrent enumeration of `wordsArray`. I create a new instance of `MyWordClass` in each of the concurrent iterations. Finally, I use a `@synchronized` block to accumulate the results.

```
NSArray *wordsArray = @[@[@"a", @"b", @"c"], @[@"1", @"2", @"3"]];

NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[wordsArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent usingBlock:^(NSArray *wordList, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    // The scores are being calculated concurrently
    NSDictionary *scores = [[MyWordClass new] wordScore:wordList];

    @synchronized(result) {
        [result addEntriesFromDictionary:scores];
    }
}];

NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Important take aways are 1) do a concurrent enumeration, 2) don't use shared instances in the concurrent block, and 3) use a `@synchronized` block to gather the result.